# Additional textfield for taxonomy term reference field

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, forms

In the site, which I develop, I need to have workers, who provide specific services. Each worker for specific services has their own prices. Workers are drupal users, Services are drupal taxonomy terms of vocabulary services. For users I have created term reference field (called field_services) with the multiselect check boxes widget.

In the user edit form, when services are selected, I need to show additional textfield (price) for each service, how can I achieve that? Is it possible to do that with [field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection), because I didn't succeed. Or should I use hook_form_alter and create a column in table field_data_field_services of my drupal database? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why did field collection not work?

Comment: altering default tables is not good practice, need to find some other way.